# multiline values in a column while spark read file

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have data as below and I need to separate that based on "`,`"

```
I/p file : 1,2,4,371003\,5371022\,87200000\,U
```

The desired result should be :

> ```
> a  b  c   d   e                           f
> 1  2  3   4   371003,5371022,87000000     U
> ```

```
val df = spark.read.option("inferSchma","true").option("escape","\\").option("delimiter",",").csv("/user/txt.csv")
```

Comment: What is your question/problem? (You haven't actually specified any question here). Regarding what I think you are asking: My guess would be that you have to read it as a text file and split on `,` yourself. See e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452692/spark-2-0-scala-read-csv-files-with-escaped-delimiters and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53672800/spark-to-parse-backslash-escaped-comma-in-csv-files-that-are-not-enclosed-by-quo

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
val df = spark.read.csv("/user/txt.csv")
df.show()

+---+---+---+-------+--------+---------+---+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|    _c3|     _c4|      _c5|_c6|
+---+---+---+-------+--------+---------+---+
|  1|  2|  4|371003\|5371022\|87200000\|  U|
+---+---+---+-------+--------+---------+---+



df.select(
    '_c0, '_c1, '_c2,
    regexp_replace(concat_ws(",", '_c3, '_c4, '_c5), "\\\\", ""),
    '_c6
  ).toDF("a","b","c","e","f").show(false)

+---+---+---+-----------------------+---+
|a  |b  |c  |e                      |f  |
+---+---+---+-----------------------+---+
|1  |2  |4  |371003,5371022,87200000|U  |
+---+---+---+-----------------------+---+
```